# Throwing OutOfMemory Error(Byte to Base64)

Tags: android, android-studio, bitmap

I have an database, And I have some large images to convert it to base64.
And when I'm saving it to database, I received this error.

```
11-17 11:56:03.359 11549-11620/? E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 63489036 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 47MB until OOM"
11-17 11:56:03.359 11549-11620/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-792
11-17 11:56:03.359 11549-11620/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.juandirection, PID: 11549
11-17 11:56:03.359 11549-11620/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 63489036 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 47MB until OOM
11-17 11:56:03.359 11549-11620/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
11-17 11:56:03.359 11549-11620/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
11-17 11:56:03.359 11549-11620/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:635)
11-17 11:56:03.359 11549-11620/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:611)
11-17 11:56:03.359 11549-11620/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:649)
11-17 11:56:03.359 11549-11620/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.juandirection.Review$9.getParams(Review.java:206)
11-17 11:56:03.359 11549-11620/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.volley.Request.getBody(Request.java:468)
11-17 11:56:03.359 11549-11620/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:253)
11-17 11:56:03.359 11549-11620/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:227)
11-17 11:56:03.359 11549-11620/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:107)
11-17 11:56:03.359 11549-11620/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:97)
11-17 11:56:03.359 11549-11620/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:114)
```

My image is around 6MB.
Some are around just KB. Kb images works fine but when i upload with 6mb image size, i got that error.

```
  @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    //String filepath = "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/20150426_085939.jpg";
                    String filepath = Global.SELECTED_IMAGES.get(valueThisIteration);
                    String newFilePath = filepath.substring(7,filepath.length());
                    File imagefile = new File(newFilePath);
                    FileInputStream fis = null;
                    try {
                        fis = new FileInputStream(imagefile);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70 , baos);
                    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
                    String encImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    parameters.put("latitude", Global.lat);
                    parameters.put("imagepath", encImage);
                    return parameters;
                }
```

Comment: try to add bm.recycle();

What resolution is your Image? As far as i know, if you decode an image to bitmap without bitmapotions, it takes 4 times the count of pixels size in memory (so for a 2 Megapixel Image it would be 8 Megabyte).

The byte Array takes space, too and the base 64 String takes even more space.

Comment: The image is 6mb. I view the details of image but the resolution is not available. The image is taken from my gallery of my device(Samsung Galaxy s5).

Comment: Most likely the image is 16MP (because Bitmapfactory wants to allocate 64MB ob Memory). 
Do you really need to decode the image? You can convert the fileinputstream to a byte array directly. 
Do you really need this high resolution? Take a look at http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html to  see how to reduce the memory needed.

Comment: well as to save it as Base64 to database, I really need to decode the image.  
When i change the bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70 , baos); to bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10 , baos); errors gone. what is the second parameter of the compress? will it affect the image resolution?

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting `android:largeHeap="true"` in the application tag of `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Something like below:

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true" />
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Do not store any bitmap or base64 string inside hash map or array list just store the path of image and when you want to use image then get bitmap or base64 image string from that path its good practice so inside

```
  Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

this map only store address path  of the image

Comment: Yep its a good practice. But My app requires an offline database.
so im storing my image trough web server and update the sqlite database of android app when the user is online. so that the user can still view the images. So I need to save base64image and decode it.

Comment: when you inserting base64 string inside database first get image path from hashnap and get base64 string from that path one by one  do not store all images base64 strings inside hashmap.

Comment: Okay sir. I'll try your suggestion. But I'm using StringBuilder, is there anyway to put parameters?

Comment: where are you Using stringBuilder ?

Comment: Sorry. I mean stringrequest.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to change the resolution of the image. Android simply can't store that big of an image, as it takes up way too much memory.

Comment: How can i change the resolution? Not the size. I mean, it would be the same size as the image i uploaded but not clearer as the original.

Comment: You would have to change the second parameter in the bm.compress(). The second parameter is the quality (1-100). http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)